# Styling label of a select list

Tags: forms, theming

I want to style the label of my select list with bold font and give it some color.

This is the code for rendering form which I am using in a hook_block_view

```
  $form['dropdown_first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'City',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#prefix' => '<div style="font-weight:bold; color:#FFF">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $selected,
    '#ajax' => array(

      'callback' => 'get_citylocations_dropdown',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
    ),
  );
```

The #prefix and #suffix is wrapping entire select list and effecting/applying the select list which is not I want. I just want to style the `<label>City</label>` to something like`<label style='my style code goes here'>City</label>`

Its not working as I expected.

How do i do it?

Comment: Simple answer: don't. Use CSS selectors to target the desired label as you would with any element.

Comment: @Clive I dint get you. Are you saying don't style using form api? or its not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you insist on using Form API for this, but form element labels are rendered in [`theme_form_element_label()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element_label/7). You may want to override that function in your theme's template.tpl.php file to produce the desired markup.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in drupal can be themed, form elements can be themed as well.
you will need to take these steps:

- First of all introduce your theme function to drupal using hook_theme
- Then in your code add '#theme' property to your element
- In final step theme your element as you wish in corresponding theme function

a simple code can be like below :

```
function Mymodule_theme() {
  'my_custom_form_element_output' => array(
    'render element' => 'element',
    'template' => 'themes/my-custom-form-element-output',
  );
}


$form['dropdown_first'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'City',
  '#options' => $options_first,
  '#prefix' => '<div style="font-weight:bold; color:#FFF">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#default_value' => $selected,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'get_citylocations_dropdown',
    'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
  ),
  '#theme' => 'my_custom_form_element_output',
);
```

and finally in my-custom-form-element-output.tpl.php

```
<label style='my style code goes here'><?php print $element['title]; ?></label>//or something like that, you can check how label is stored in $element using kpr() or dsm()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the styling using CSS, something like `.classname label{ font-weight:bold; color:#FFF; }` . Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: I did not down voted, but I want to achieve it through inline style via **form api**